# Correcting probabilities when outcome is used twice

Tags: probability

I am facing the following problem:

Let's say I want to create a list by random drawing that includes elements 1, 2 and 3 with given probabilities P(1), P(2) and P(3) = 1 - (P(1) + P(2)).

As example assume P(1) is 0.9 and P(2) is 0.05. A very large result list will then consist of approx. 90% instances of element 1, 5% instances of element 2 and 5% instances of element 3.

Now let's suppose that **each time P(1) occurs two elements of 1 are inserted** into the list. For P(2) and P(3) there is still only one insertation happening per draw.

The result list will now no longer include the elements with the given probabilities but will be skewed towards more instances of element 1.

How should the probabilities of drawing elements 1 and 2 now be corrected so that the list contains the elements 1,2,3 again with the given fixed probabilities [P(1) = 0.9, P(2) = 0.05, P(3) = 1 - (P(1) + P(2))]?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you make $P(1)=p$ and draw $n$ times, you now expect $2np\ 1$s, $\frac 12(1-p)n\ 2$'s and $\frac 12(1-p)n\ 3$'s.  As you want $0.9$ of the elements of the list to be $1'$s you want 
$$\frac {2p}{2p+1-p}=0.9\\
2p=0.9+0.9p\\
p=\frac{0.9}{1.1}\approx 0.8182$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However if P(2) can't be expressed as 1/2 * (1-p) because P(2) might be smaller or greater than P(3), P(2) also needs to be corrected (i believe?) How would i go about that?

Comment: Actually that doesn't matter as long as you want the final list to be $0.9\ 1$s.  Then the total chance of $2$ and $3$ is $1-p$ and the calculation goes through.  The remark that each has chance $\frac 12(1-p)$ would not be correct.

Comment: Great! Now i got it. Thank you very much for your help.